# Python Facebook SDK: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, module

I am trying to run a basic example with the Facebook SDK for Python. I tried doing exactly what this [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/littleq0903/introduction-to-facebook-python-api) does from the command line (with "`pip install facebook`" and "`pip install facebook-sdk`" successfully done first...):

[image]

`import Facebook` works okay, but `graph = facebook.GraphAPI()` gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'
```

I'm not imtimately familiar with how modules work, but it looks like `facebook` somehow isn't recognized at all! Or something else is missing here. From the command line, I tried these things to investigate:

```
>>>dir(facebook)
```

Output:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
```

and...

```
>>>help(facebook)
```

Output:

```
Help on package facebook:

NAME
    facebook - TODO: Document your package.

FILE
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Facebook-0.0-py2.7.egg/facebook/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS


DATA
    __loader__ = <zipimporter object "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Fa...
    __version__ = 'TODO: Enter a version'

VERSION
    TODO: Enter a version

(END)
```

...But I'm still stuck. Do I need to "enter a version" to somehow get the thing to fully instantiate? Or could it be something else?

Comment: In my case, I only forgot to activate my virtualenv...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian, Just execute the following commands to get this working

```
sudo pip uninstall facebook
sudo pip uninstall facebook-sdk
sudo pip install facebook-sdk
```

For other operating systems, just remove `facebook` and `facebook-sdk` packages and install only `facebook-sdk`.

And then execute that program, it will work. Looks like `facebook` module is a dummy module. What we actually need is `facebook-sdk` only.

Comment: I still get "cannot import name Facebook" error. is it deprecated?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled as suggested. I can't import facebook-sdk only import facebook. When I import facebook and use facebook.GraphAPI I get the same error reported above.

Comment: I had an issue where the files were not being removed, despite `pip2 uninstall` and the `apt remove --purge`.  I had to manually remove the files, as in the answer provided by @Meistro.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem when messing around with facebook-sdk for python the first time. It occured I named my python file "facebook.py", and made unconsiously a name clash.

Comment: Same here! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I fell for that too :]

Comment: This answer saved loads of time for me :'D ... Same here

Comment: Ha! Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried what @thefourtheye suggested but pip wasn't uninstalling everything. Instead, I just cleaned out the Facebook packages via

```
rm -rf /path/to/my/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook* && rm -rf /path/to/my/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Facebook*
```

WARNING: check that you don't have any other packages that start with `facebook` before you go removing anything. In my case I had

```
facebook/    
Facebook-0.0-py2.7.egg-info/   
facebook.py    
facebook.pyc 
facebook_sdk-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info/
```

Comment: I prefer to run `ls -r` first, then recall the command and change `ls` to `rm`. :)  So; `ls -r /path/to/my/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/[fF]acebook*` first, then just change the ls to rm (the `-f` isn't necessary with rm in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I renamed the file from *facebook.py* to *first.py* and it worked! So,  my conclusion is don't save file with a module name.

Answer (score 0):

I checked everything because i had the same problem, i uninstalled and installed as the the recommendations, i checked if there is another file, package facebook, and no worked, then i saw i had this in my program graph = facebook.**GraphApi**(token)  , ....Api.. A uppercase and the following letters lowercase, then I typed like this, [image: Result] graph = facebook.**GraphAPI**(token)  , API uppercase all of them, now after i validated access token and checked other little bug everything was working PERFECTLY.

Good luck.