# How to install facebook-sdk for python in ubuntu?

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to install facebook-sdk for python to fetch data from few fb pages.

I have tried following commands as i saw in [Python Facebook SDK: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893523/python-facebook-sdk-module-object-has-no-attribute-graphapi)

```
__sudo pip uninstall facebook  
sudo pip uninstall facebook-sdk  
sudo pip install facebook-sdk__
```

But i am getting following in my terminal

```
_User@user:~$ __sudo pip install facebook-sdk__  
Downloading/unpacking facebook-sdk  
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/  
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement facebook-sdk   
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for facebook-sdk  
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log_
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of pip do you have?

This error I remember:
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

As far as I can remember I think i found the issue with some older versions of OpenSSL being incompatible with pip 1.3.1:

Installing pip-1.2.1 is a working workaround, but let me know!